# Как достать из текста определенные слова?

Tags: python

Вот есть текст:

```
hostname:  Super Server
version :  48/1.1.2.2/Stdio 2930 secure  (70)
tcp/ip  :  185.188.182.226:27015
map     :  bootbox at: 0 x, 0 y, 0 z
players :  3 active (16 max)

#      name userid uniqueid frag time ping loss adr
# 1 "Player1" 959 STEAM_0:0:551111876   4  1:02:20   30    0 
# 2     "Player2" 985 STEAM_0:0:530771113  40 00:40   28    0 
# 3 "Player3" 979 STEAM_0:0:230124678   6 13:10   36    0 
3 users
```

Мне нужно из него достать слова начинающие на **STEAM_** и также достать последующее за ним число

Очень буду рад за вашу помощь)

Comment: Что-то типа `STEAM_(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)` (группы \d+ добавляйте/убавляйте в зависимости от чисел, которые хотите получить, из вопроса не совсем понятно)

Answer (score 2):

Если вам здесь особо мудрить не нужно и данные примерно в одном виде приходят, то есть, то, что вам нужно получить, а именно STEAM всегда такой, то можно сделать так:

```
text = """
hostname:  Super Server
version :  48/1.1.2.2/Stdio 2930 secure  (70)
tcp/ip  :  185.188.182.226:27015
map     :  bootbox at: 0 x, 0 y, 0 z
players :  3 active (16 max)

#      name userid uniqueid frag time ping loss adr
# 1 "Player1" 959 STEAM_0:0:551111876   4  1:02:20   30    0 
# 2     "Player2" 985 STEAM_0:0:530771113  40 00:40   28    0 
# 3 "Player3" 979 STEAM_0:0:230124678   6 13:10   36    0 
3 users
"""

for line in text.splitlines():
    for item in line.split():
        if item.startswith("STEAM"):
            num = item.split("_")[1]
            print(num)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли